# How to configure a custom date format for ActiveWeb templates

Tags: javalite, activeweb

The [views docs](http://javalite.io/views) have an example of number format configuration:

```
public class FreeMarkerConfig extends AbstractFreeMarkerConfig {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        //this is to override a strange FreeMarker default processing of numbers
        getConfiguration().setNumberFormat("0.##");
     }
}
```

What is the right syntax to use for a custom date, time format in the below code:

```
getConfiguration().setDateFormat("what comes here ?????");
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The method `getConfiguration()` simply returns an instance of `freemarker.template.Configuration`, which gives you a direct access to configure FreeMarker any way you want. Please, refer to [FreeMarker Configuration](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/Configuration.html) docs to see what is possible.

Comment: Cool, thank you ! I didn't find their API docs. Now I know where it s hidden :)

Comment: Yeah, it is [here](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/core/Configurable.html#setDateTimeFormat-java.lang.String-) to be more precise :)